# Sublime Text 3: I can't search a string with a dollar followed by underscore ($_GET, $_POST, etc.)

Tags: search, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I can search the following without problems:

- `_GET`
- `$variable`

However, sublime fails to search `$_` (p.e. `$_GET`.) I have tried to escape it somehow:

- `$\_GET`
- `\$_GET`
- `$__GET`

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off the regular expressions search. It is the button on the far left of the search field (in this picture currently selected):

[image: Non working example]

With regular expressions turned off:

[image: Working example]

Although I'm not sure if this would fit your exact problem since you tried escaping using `\$_`, this answer may still help for posterity.

**Did you also make sure "whole word" search is turned off?** That's the 3rd button from the left (next to the `Aa`)

With whole word turned on:

[image: Non working example 2]

Failing with the attempted escaped `\$_`:

[image: Failed $_ escaped search]

And it succeeding with `_GET`:

[image: _GET example]

Note that whole word search of `$_` would succeed if there was a whole `$_` phrase, surrounded by whitespace. For example with whole word search on:

> I am a sentence with the keyword $_ which will be matched.

would work, whereas:

> I am a sentence with the keyword $_GET, which will never match. $_POST, $_REQUEST, and $_SERVER won't work either.

would break the whole word search.

Comment: I had the _whole word_ option enabled. After disabling it, it finds the  variable correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Was about to break my keyboard out of frustration :P